# Single ext4 Drive Seen as RAID

Tags: hard-drive, raid, clone

I have a WD My Passport 8TB drive that I hang off of a Raspberry Pi 4 to serve as a home server so I can share files amongst the many devices in my home.

As a hardware backup, every year I buy a new 8TB My Passport drive and clone the previous drive.  This year I cannot seem to clone last year's drive to the new drive because Clonezilla keeps seeing last years drive as a RAID... at least I think it does.

The multiple attempts I've made using Clonezilla always result in Clonezilla's GUI showing cloning /dev/sdd to /dev/sdd instead of cloning /dev/sdc (the source drive) to /dev/sdd (the new drive).  The first time I tried, I know this was happening because the end result was a new drive full of the same zeros as before the clone.

I am seeing something about Clonezilla failing to load a RAID before the GUI screen pops up and takes over.  Does anyone know of a switch I can use to tell Clonezilla that the old device is NOT a RAID (it isn't).

If not, what is the fastest way that I can copy the data with all permissions from the old drive to the new drive.  I don't want to spend the week or more that DD is going to take, as that attempt resulted in just over 200GB copied in just under 10 hours.

Comment: You probably forgot `-bs` and `dd` was copying 512B at a time. Please [edit] your post and add details about which options you're selecting in Clonezilla and what error messages you're seeing (verbatim).

Comment: I used bs=1024 because I read that higher blocks didn't make a significant difference in speed.  Concerning Clonezilla, I used all of the preset beginner choices for local to to local disk.

Comment: It's exactly the opposite: `dd` uses sector size by default (ie. 512 or 4096 depending on drive) and that makes it very slow because the overhead is huge (copying 1 MB is 2048 or 256 operations, while with `-bs 1M` it would be 1 op). https://askubuntu.com/a/523043/129094

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just mounting both drives and doing a `sudo cp -rp {source} {destination}` copy which actually only took somewhere around 6 hours since the drive only contained ~2.2 - 2.3 TB of files.

When I completed the copy and removed the previous drive that I was backing up, I contemplated changing the UUID in `/etc/fstab` for the new drive's UUID, but instead just unmounted the new drive and changed the UUID with tune2fs to mach the previous drive.  Upon rebooting, everything appears to be fine now.

Someone please chime in if changing the UUID in `/etc/fstab` to the UUID of the new drive was a better choice than my changing the new drive's UUID to match the previous drive.

Comment: I'd update fstab with the new UUID. UUID stands for _Universally Unique IDentifier_. Now you have two non-unique UUIDs and plugging in both of these drives simultaneously can cause some unpredictable behavior with software that (reasonably) assumes uniqueness of UUIDs.